# How can I get the highest of float number?

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point

I read some codes in libgcc:

```
UDWtype __fixunsxfDI (XFtype a)
{
  if (a < 0)
    return 0;

  /* Compute high word of result, as a flonum.  */
  const XFtype b = (a / Wtype_MAXp1_F);
  /* Convert that to fixed (but not to DWtype!),
     and shift it into the high word.  */
  UDWtype v = (UWtype) b;
  v <<= W_TYPE_SIZE;
  /* Remove high part from the XFtype, leaving the low part as flonum.  */
  a -= (XFtype)v;
  /* Convert that to fixed (but not to DWtype!) and add it in.
     Sometimes A comes out negative.  This is significant, since
     A has more bits than a long int does.  */
  if (a < 0)
    v -= (UWtype) (- a);
  else
    v += (UWtype) a;
  return v;
}
```

about XFType:

```
typedef     float XFtype    __attribute__ ((mode (XF)));
```

about Wtype_MAXp1_F：

```
#if W_TYPE_SIZE == 8
# define Wtype_MAXp1_F  0x1p8f
#elif W_TYPE_SIZE == 16
# define Wtype_MAXp1_F  0x1p16f
#elif W_TYPE_SIZE == 32
# define Wtype_MAXp1_F  0x1p32f
#elif W_TYPE_SIZE == 64
# define Wtype_MAXp1_F  0x1p64f
#else
# error "expand the table"
#endif
```

I think XFType is 96bits float and 0x1p32f is 1^32.

what's

const XFtype b = (a / Wtype_MAXp1_F)

means ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Your subject line says "how can I get the highest of float number", but then you don't seem to be asking that in the actual question. Do you want to know the largest number a `float` can hold?

Comment: 1^32 does not differ that much from 1, that's rather 2^32

Answer (score 0):

“0x1p32f” is 2<sup>32</sup> and has type `float`. This is the hexadecimal floating-point format. The part after the “0x” and before the “p” is interpreted as a hexadecimal numeral and may include a radix point, so that, in “0x3.5p1”, the “3.5” means 3 + 5/16 = 3.3125<sub>10</sub>. The number after the “p” is an integer that indicates the power of two to multiply by the first part. So “0x1p32f” is 1•2<sup>32</sup>, and “0x3.5p-1” is 3.3125<sub>10</sub>•2<sup>-1</sup> = 1.65625<sub>10</sub>. The suffixes are the same as for decimal floating-point constants: “f” or “F” means `float`, no suffix means `double`, and “l” or “L” means `long double`.

`a / Wtype_MAXp1_F` divides `a` by two to the power of the number of bits in some word size. Thus, if the word size represented by `W_TYPE_SIZE` is 32 bit, then `a / Wtype_MAXp1_F` divides `a` by 2<sup>32</sup>. It appears to be part of some extended-precision arithmetic; it is separating `a` into some “high bits” and some “low bits”.

In C, you can get the maximum finite floating-point number by including `<float.h>` and using `FLT_MAX` for the maximum finite `float`, `DBL_MAX` for the maximum finite `double`, and `LDBL_MAX` for the maximum finite `long double`. These values are much larger than `Wtype_MAXp1_F`. If it is available on your platform, you can get the highest `float` value, which is infinity, by including `<math.h>` and using `INFINITY`.